# Why do i get this error message on xstate createMachine

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xstate-react

I just created react app by using
`npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript`

then installed xstate using
`npm install xstate --save`

after importing
`import { createMachine } from "xstate";`
i get the error provided on screenshot, couldn't find any answer to that problem, any ideas?

my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { createMachine } from "xstate";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>Hello</div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
ERROR in node_modules/xstate/dist/declarations/src/setup.d.ts:54:21
TS1139: Type parameter declaration expected.
    52 |     [K in RequiredSetupKeys<TChildrenMap>]: unknown;
    53 | }): {
  > 54 |     createMachine: <const TConfig extends MachineConfig<TContext, TEvent, ToProvidedActor<TChildrenMap, TActors>, ToParameterizedObject<TActions>, ToParameterizedObject<TGuards>, TDelay, TTag, TInput, TOutput, TEmitted, ResolveTypegenMeta<TypegenDisabled, TEvent, ToProvidedActor<TChildrenMap, TActors>, ToParameterizedObject<TActions>, ToParameterizedObject<TGuards>, TDelay, TTag, TEmitted>>>(config: TConfig) => StateMachine<TContext, TEvent, Cast<ToChildren<ToProvidedActor<TChildrenMap, TActors>>, Record<string, AnyActorRef | undefined>>, ToProvidedActor<TChildrenMap, TActors>, ToParameterizedObject<TActions>, ToParameterizedObject<TGuards>, TDelay, ToStateValue<TConfig>, TTag, TInput, TOutput, TEmitted, ResolveTypegenMeta<TypegenDisabled, TEvent, ToProvidedActor<TChildrenMap, TActors>, ToParameterizedObject<TActions>, ToParameterizedObject<TGuards>, TDelay, TTag, TEmitted>>;
       |                     ^^^^^
    55 | };
    56 | export {};
    57 |

ERROR in node_modules/xstate/dist/declarations/src/setup.d.ts:54:27
TS1005: ';' expected.
    52 |     [K in RequiredSetupKeys<TChildrenMap>]: unknown;
    53 | }): {
  > 54 |     createMachine: <const TConfig extends MachineConfig<TContext, TEvent, ToProvidedActor<TChildrenMap, TActors>, ToParameterizedObject<TActions>, ToParameterizedObject<TGuards>, TDelay, TTag, TInput, TOutput, TEmitted, ResolveTypegenMeta<TypegenDisabled, TEvent, ToProvidedActor<TChildrenMap, TActors>, ToParameterizedObject<TActions>, ToParameterizedObject<TGuards>, TDelay, TTag, TEmitted>>>(config: TConfig) => StateMachine<TContext, TEvent, Cast<ToChildren<ToProvidedActor<TChildrenMap, TActors>>, Record<string, AnyActorRef | undefined>>, ToProvidedActor<TChildrenMap, TActors>, ToParameterizedObject<TActions>, ToParameterizedObject<TGuards>, TDelay, ToStateValue<TConfig>, TTag, TInput, TOutput, TEmitted, ResolveTypegenMeta<TypegenDisabled, TEvent, ToProvidedActor<TChildrenMap, TActors>, ToParameterizedObject<TActions>, ToParameterizedObject<TGuards>, TDelay, TTag, TEmitted>>;
       |                           ^^^^^^^
    55 | };
    56 | export {};
    57 |

ERROR in node_modules/xstate/dist/declarations/src/setup.d.ts:54:35
TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
    52 |     [K in RequiredSetupKeys<TChildrenMap>]: unknown;
    53 | }): {
  > 54 |     createMachine: <const TConfig extends MachineConfig<TContext, TEvent, ToProvidedActor<TChildrenMap, TActors>, ToParameterizedObject<TActions>, ToParameterizedObject<TGuards>, TDelay, TTag, TInput, TOutput, TEmitted, ResolveTypegenMeta<TypegenDisabled, TEvent, ToProvidedActor<TChildrenMap, TActors>, ToParameterizedObject<TActions>, ToParameterizedObject<TGuards>, TDelay, TTag, TEmitted>>>(config: TConfig) => StateMachine<TContext, TEvent, Cast<ToChildren<ToProvidedActor<TChildrenMap, TActors>>, Record<string, AnyActorRef | undefined>>, ToProvidedActor<TChildrenMap, TActors>, ToParameterizedObject<TActions>, ToParameterizedObject<TGuards>, TDelay, ToStateValue<TConfig>, TTag, TInput, TOutput, TEmitted, ResolveTypegenMeta<TypegenDisabled, TEvent, ToProvidedActor<TChildrenMap, TActors>, ToParameterizedObject<TActions>, ToParameterizedObject<TGuards>, TDelay, TTag, TEmitted>>;
       |                                   ^^^^^^^
    55 | };
    56 | export {};
    57 |

ERROR in node_modules/xstate/dist/declarations/src/setup.d.ts:54:402
TS1005: ')' expected.
    52 |     [K in RequiredSetupKeys<TChildrenMap>]: unknown;
    53 | }): {
  > 54 |     createMachine: <const TConfig extends MachineConfig<TContext, TEvent, ToProvidedActor<TChildrenMap, TActors>, ToParameterizedObject<TActions>, ToParameterizedObject<TGuards>, TDelay, TTag, TInput, TOutput, TEmitted, ResolveTypegenMeta<TypegenDisabled, TEvent, ToProvidedActor<TChildrenMap, TActors>, ToParameterizedObject<TActions>, ToParameterizedObject<TGuards>, TDelay, TTag, TEmitted>>>(config: TConfig) => StateMachine<TContext, TEvent, Cast<ToChildren<ToProvidedActor<TChildrenMap, TActors>>, Record<string, AnyActorRef | undefined>>, ToProvidedActor<TChildrenMap, TActors>, ToParameterizedObject<TActions>, ToParameterizedObject<TGuards>, TDelay, ToStateValue<TConfig>, TTag, TInput, TOutput, TEmitted, ResolveTypegenMeta<TypegenDisabled, TEvent, ToProvidedActor<TChildrenMap, TActors>, ToParameterizedObject<TActions>, ToParameterizedObject<TGuards>, TDelay, TTag, TEmitted>>;
       |

                                                                                                                                    ^      
    55 | };
    56 | export {};
    57 |

ERROR in node_modules/xstate/dist/declarations/src/setup.d.ts:54:404
TS1434: Unexpected keyword or identifier.
    52 |     [K in RequiredSetupKeys<TChildrenMap>]: unknown;
    53 | }): {
  > 54 |     createMachine: <const TConfig extends MachineConfig<TContext, TEvent, ToProvidedActor<TChildrenMap, TActors>, ToParameterizedObject<TActions>, ToParameterizedObject<TGuards>, TDelay, TTag, TInput, TOutput, TEmitted, ResolveTypegenMeta<TypegenDisabled, TEvent, ToProvidedActor<TChildrenMap, TActors>, ToParameterizedObject<TActions>, ToParameterizedObject<TGuards>, TDelay, TTag, TEmitted>>>(config: TConfig) => StateMachine<TContext, TEvent, Cast<ToChildren<ToProvidedActor<TChildrenMap, TActors>>, Record<string, AnyActorRef | undefined>>, ToProvidedActor<TChildrenMap, TActors>, ToParameterizedObject<TActions>, ToParameterizedObject<TGuards>, TDelay, ToStateValue<TConfig>, TTag, TInput, TOutput, TEmitted, ResolveTypegenMeta<TypegenDisabled, TEvent, ToProvidedActor<TChildrenMap, TActors>, ToParameterizedObject<TActions>, ToParameterizedObject<TGuards>, TDelay, TTag, TEmitted>>;
       |

                                                                                                                                      ^^^^^^^
    55 | };
    56 | export {};
    57 |

ERROR in node_modules/xstate/dist/declarations/src/setup.d.ts:54:411
TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
    52 |     [K in RequiredSetupKeys<TChildrenMap>]: unknown;
    53 | }): {
  > 54 |     createMachine: <const TConfig extends MachineConfig<TContext, TEvent, ToProvidedActor<TChildrenMap, TActors>, ToParameterizedObject<TActions>, ToParameterizedObject<TGuards>, TDelay, TTag, TInput, TOutput, TEmitted, ResolveTypegenMeta<TypegenDisabled, TEvent, ToProvidedActor<TChildrenMap, TActors>, ToParameterizedObject<TActions>, ToParameterizedObject<TGuards>, TDelay, TTag, TEmitted>>>(config: TConfig) => StateMachine<TContext, TEvent, Cast<ToChildren<ToProvidedActor<TChildrenMap, TActors>>, Record<string, AnyActorRef | undefined>>, ToProvidedActor<TChildrenMap, TActors>, ToParameterizedObject<TActions>, ToParameterizedObject<TGuards>, TDelay, ToStateValue<TConfig>, TTag, TInput, TOutput, TEmitted, ResolveTypegenMeta<TypegenDisabled, TEvent, ToProvidedActor<TChildrenMap, TActors>, ToParameterizedObject<TActions>, ToParameterizedObject<TGuards>, TDelay, TTag, TEmitted>>;
       |


  ^
    55 | };
    56 | export {};
    57 |

ERROR in node_modules/xstate/dist/declarations/src/setup.d.ts:54:413
TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
    52 |     [K in RequiredSetupKeys<TChildrenMap>]: unknown;
    53 | }): {
  > 54 |     createMachine: <const TConfig extends MachineConfig<TContext, TEvent, ToProvidedActor<TChildrenMap, TActors>, ToParameterizedObject<TActions>, ToParameterizedObject<TGuards>, TDelay, TTag, TInput, TOutput, TEmitted, ResolveTypegenMeta<TypegenDisabled, TEvent, ToProvidedActor<TChildrenMap, TActors>, ToParameterizedObject<TActions>, ToParameterizedObject<TGuards>, TDelay, TTag, TEmitted>>>(config: TConfig) => StateMachine<TContext, TEvent, Cast<ToChildren<ToProvidedActor<TChildrenMap, TActors>>, Record<string, AnyActorRef | undefined>>, Toe<TConfig>, TTag, TInput, TOutput, TEmitted, ResolveTypegenMeta<TypegenDisabled, TEvent, ToProvidedActor<TChildrenMap, TAce<TConfig>, TTag,tors>, ToParameterizedObject<TActions>, ToParameterizedObject<TGuards>, TDelay, TTag, TEmitted>>;                         rizedObject<TActi


                                                       ^^
    55 | };
    56 | export {};
    57 |

ERROR in node_modules/xstate/dist/declarations/src/setup.d.ts:55:1
TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
    53 | }): {
    54 |     createMachine: <const TConfig extends MachineConfig<TContext, TEvent, ToProvidedActor<TChildrenMap, TActors>, ToParameterizedObject<TActions>, ToParameterizedObject<TGuards>, TDelay, TTag, TInput, TOutput, TEmitted, ResolveTypegenMeta<TypegenDisabled, TEvent, ToProvidedActor<TChildrenMap, TActors>, ToParameterizedObject<TActions>, ToParameterizedObject<TGuards>, TDelay, TTag, TEmit<TGuards>, TDelay, TTag, TEmitted>>>(config: TConfig) => StateMachine<TContext, TEvent, Cast<ToChildren<ToProvidedActor<T<string, AnyActorRef | undefinChildrenMap, TActors>>, Record<string, AnyActorRef | undefined>>, ToProvidedActor<TChildrenMap, TActors>, ToParameterizedOtateValue<TConfig>, TTag, TInpbject<TActions>, ToParameterizedObject<TGuards>, TDelay, ToStateValue<TConfig>, TTag, TInput, TOutput, TEmitted, ResolveTyObject<TActions>, ToParameteripegenMeta<TypegenDisabled, TEvent, ToProvidedActor<TChildrenMap, TActors>, ToParameterizedObject<TActions>, ToParameterizedObject<TGuards>, TDelay, TTag, TEmitted>>;
  > 55 | };
       | ^
    56 | export {};
    57 |
```

Comment: Share the code as text not as photo or video file please. Why? : [read this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: It is just basic react app and installed xstate with import, nothing more

Comment: [Why you shouldn't share code/data/error as photo or video file](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Very well, you edited your question!

Comment: fixed, hope it helps

Comment: It seems that create-react-app is shipping an old version of typescript, if you bump the typescript to 5.3.2 in package.json it looks like it works

Comment: By the way, the react documentation no longer recommends using create-react-app, they suggest using a framework https://react.dev/learn/start-a-new-react-project . Using vite is also very simple if you don't want to learn a framework

Comment: Thank you, you are right, create-react-app is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

You must use TypeScript version 5 and higher, which includes support for `const` type parameters. See https://stately.ai/docs/typescript for more information.